# Need advice, previous parked domain not indexing on Google

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing

I originally bought the domain ([www.iconicphotos.co.uk](http://www.iconicphotos.co.uk)) a while ago, I then decided to try and sell it on Sedo. The domain was up for sale for a few months before I noticed that the ads being pulled through on the parked domain were porn based (Not happy about this!). Anyhow recently created a gallery site to sell my artwork from but I am finding now that the site isn't being indexed at all! I had a couple of pages appear a few days ago but for only a couple of hours before they were removed. If you try the non www version of the domain using (site) there are a couple of pages but they are they show the old parked domain info.

I have created a WMT account and updated it with a new sitemap. I have also submitted the site again using the fetch as google bot option. Not sure what to do now?

Comment: How long ago did you do all of this?

Comment: The domain was parked I would say less than 6 months ago. The new content has been on the site for less than a week I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have anything to worry about based on the time frame in the discussion above.  You've already done all you can by unparking the domain, adding content, adding a sitemap, and fetching as Googlebot.  You need to give the index some time to catch up to the new content.  Make sure you have a robots.txt file that is not telling the bot to go away or otherwise doing something self-defeating.

Keep an eye on the server access logs as well as check GWT for the requests for the sitemap and robots.txt files.  As long as Google is seeing you properly, the indexing will come back over time as the negatives from the porn ads drop out of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Google will take some time to index your web pages after submitting your sitemap in webmaster tool.

Try to make some good quality backlinks in a while.

Also, submit with unique content to search engine and not doing spamming.

Submit your website to different search engines and ping your site to search engines.

After few days Type site:yourdomain.com and you will find all the pages which will be indexed by google.